# Correct usage of the word "iteration"?

Tags: iteration

In the context of looping statements the word "iteration" appears to be commonly used by many programmers to mean the execution of the body of a loop.  However, every definition of "iteration" I've found, both in programming and non-programming contexts, states that it means repetition.  Thus, the body of a 3-iteration loop would actually be executed 4 times.

Is there some other concise term that would mean the total number of executions or is the misuse of "iteration" just a "gentleman's agreement" born out of a lack of any other convenient way to refer to the total number of executions?  This misuse would be similar to using the phrase "passing/returning an array" in C when in reality what gets passed/returned is a pointer to the array's first element.

Comment: I think "iteration" isn't the "repeats of a step", it's a "step that repeats". If it's executed four times, there are four iterations.

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, I often ask myself questions of this kind. I don't think it's the right place to ask them, though... Check out ell.stackexchange.com or english.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko - Don't feel too bad. As a native English speaker I continually ask myself questions of this kind, especially when attempting to write technical documents :-)